# Remove all <p> with only one space inside in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I am having an issue with my code which is like :

```
<p>Some text here</p>
<p>More text here</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

I would like to remove all the `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.
It appears as `<p> </p>` with a space inside but when I copy the HTML, it shows `&nbsp;` inside.

I tried `str_replace('<p> </p> ', '', $data);` which didn't work.

I also tried `preg_replace('#<p>.*?</\1>#s', '', $data);` and it removes all the `<p>` (as it is supposed to do) but I can't achieve removing only the `<p>` with a space (or `&nbsp;` ?) inside.
Replacing `.*?` with `/\s+` doesn't work neither.

My exact PHP code is :

```
$recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_1 = explode('<article class="trajet">', $donnees_infotrafic);
$recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_2 = explode('</article>' , $recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_1[1] );
$recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_3 = preg_replace('#<p>[0-9 /]+/[0-9 /]+</p>#', '', $recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_2[0]);

$trajet_infotrafic = str_replace("/\s?<p>(\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/","",$recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_3);

echo '<!-- without str_replace1 -->';
echo $recuperer_trajet_infotrafic_3;
echo '<!-- without str_replace2 -->';
echo '<!-- with str_replace1 -->';
echo $trajet_infotrafic;
echo '<!-- with str_replace2 -->';
```

What I get in View Page Source :

```html
<!-- without str_replace1 -->
<!-- TRAJET -->
   <h3>Votre trajet</h2>
   <div class="septraf"> </div>
   <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Dans les 2 sens</span> :<br />- arrêt Mimosas reporté à l'arrêt provisoire placé route de Vannes au niveau de la station essence<br />- arrêt Cravate reporté à l'arrêt Ferrière</p>
<p> </p>
  <!-- without str_replace2 -->
  <!-- with str_replace1 -->
  <!-- TRAJET -->
   <h3>Votre trajet</h2>
   <div class="septraf"> </div>
   <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Dans les 2 sens</span> :<br />- arrêt Mimosas reporté à l'arrêt provisoire placé route de Vannes au niveau de la station essence<br />- arrêt Cravate reporté à l'arrêt Ferrière</p>
<p> </p>
  <!-- with str_replace2 -->
```

Edit : It appears that the character between the two `<p>` tags is neither a space or a `&nbsp;` because I couldn't replace it using just a `str_replace('&nbsp;','TEST',$data)` or `str_replace(' ','TEST',$data);`

Comment: Try doing this. str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p> ', '', $data);

Comment: `&nbsp;` is an html entity that is interpreted by the browser as a non-breaking space. It is treated by PHP as a string and not a literal space, so you would need to include the entity in your condition for replacement as demonstrated by @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi The same applies for all html entities, like `&copy;` not `©`

Comment: <p>( |&nbsp;)<\/p> try this regex

Comment: Neither str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p> ', '', $data); or <p>( |&nbsp;)<\/p> works

Comment: @Loïc there was an erroneous space at the end of the string to replace.`str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p> '` should have been ``str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>'`

Comment: @fyrye I did remove it when testing ;) (but doesn't work )

Comment: @Loïc please update your question with your actual data and your desired result.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: You have multiple issues, first you want to remove the empty `<p> </p>` HTML elements, and then you are using `htmlspecialchars`. Which will convert the `<` and `>` symbols to the html entities `&gt;` and `&lt;` respectively. So you won't be able to use `htmlspecialchars` and retain the HTML elements. In addition `htmlspecialchars` does not convert breaking spaces `' '` with non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` so this was misleading in your original question.

Comment: I did use htmlspecialchars only for the purpose of the question to show what I have inside $data (which comes from html parsing with filegetcontent). I only use directly $data in my code without applying htmlspecialchars

Comment: Ok I removed that portion from your question, as using `htmlspecialchars` would provide a very different output. Instead your PHP would simply be `echo $data;` then you can `Right-Click` in your browser, and click `View page source`. A new window will open that displays the plain-text output that is being received by your browser from PHP.  Copy the echo'd portion of the code from the `View page source` window in to your question.

Comment: Try using double quotes

Comment: @fyrye I updated the question with the View page source

Comment: Your `str_replace('','TEST',$data);` would need to be `str_replace(' ','TEST',$data);` to match the whitespace character.

Comment: @fyrye Yep sorry I did a mistake when retyping what I wrote in my code for testing purposes. (But it actually removes all spaces in my code EXCEPT the one in `<p> </p>` (which isn't a space I believe))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regex alternative that will look for different combinations of spaces or non-breaking space html entities in the data you can use.

### Example https://3v4l.org/treZm

```
preg_replace('/\s?<p>(\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/', '', $data);
```

Expanded match meaning

> `\s?`  optionally begins with a single whitespace character. followed
>   by `<p>(\s|&nbsp;)*</p>` a paragraph element that contains zero
>   or more whitespace character or non-breaking space html entity.

**Result**

```
<!-- TRAJET -->
    <h3>Votre trajet</h2>
    <div class="septraf"> </div>
    <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Dans les 2 sens</span> :<br />- arrêt Mimosas reporté à l'arrêt provisoire placé route de Vannes au niveau de la station essence<br />- arrêt Cravate reporté à l'arrêt Ferrière</p>
```

This will remove the following combinations:

```
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<p> &nbsp;</p>
<p> &nbsp; </p>
\s<p></p>
\s<p> </p>
\s<p>&nbsp;</p>
\s<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
\s<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
\s<p>&nbsp; </p>
\s<p> &nbsp;</p>
\s<p> &nbsp; </p>
```

> keep in mind `\s` is not a literal space, but applies to all
>   whitespace characters `\n`, `\r`, `\t` as well.
>
> If you only want to match horizontal spaces, replace `\s` with `\h`.
>
> if you only want to match literal spaces, replace `\s` with `\040` or `[ ]`

---

I believe the original issue with `str_replace` was due to the erroneous space at the end, which may not exist in the data.

```
str_replace('<p> </p> ', '', $data);
```

Should be https://3v4l.org/ptJeE

```
str_replace('<p> </p>', '', $data);
```

---

### UPDATED https://3v4l.org/huv0m

I believe the issue is related to a literal non-breaking space `\xc2\xa0`, `alt+0160` or   being added that does not match `\s`.

```
preg_replace('/\s?<p>(\s|\xc2\xa0|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/', '', $data);
```

Comment: I updated the question with the exact PHP code I'm using and the View Page Source output I get when using your solution.

Comment: @Loïc you used `str_replace` you need to use `preg_replace` with my solution

Comment: Oops sorry, I did try using preg_replace and it is still not removing my strange `<p> </p>`

Comment: @Loïc I believe I found the character sequence to physically replace the strange spaces, rather than looking for any 0-2 characters, as in your accepted answer, which could produce undesired result. Please try the updated code

Comment: Your solution did work amazingly ! I believe the character was a xc2 or a xa0. I accepted your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correct. But, you can do it like this:

```
$data = [
        "<p>Some text here</p>",
        "<p>More text here</p>",
        "<p>&nbsp;</p>",
        "<p>&nbsp;</p>",
        "<p>Some text</p>"
];

foreach($data as $key => $para) {
    if($para == "<p>&nbsp;</p>") {
        $data[$key] = ""; // new value here or just unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: All the code I am using is not separating by comas, it is a variable $data which contains all the html directly (without " and ,)

Comment: $data in my code is an array. Please show me the content of your $data variable

Comment: by doing an echo $data; I get in the console : 
   `<h3>Votre trajet</h3>
   <div class="septraf"> </div>
   <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Dans les 2 sens</span> :<br>- arrêt Mimosas reporté à l'arrêt provisoire placé route de Vannes au niveau de la station essence<br>- arrêt Cravate reporté à l'arrêt Ferrière</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: $data = str_replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "", $data);

Comment: But this works 100%. Please do htmlentites($data) and provide the output.

Comment: I provided an htmlspecialchars($data) in the question post

Comment: This should work: $data = str_replace("<p> </p>", "", $data);

Comment: It is one of the first thing I tried but it doesn’t work. I think the space character has something special with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well Try This And Let Me Know

```
  $new_str = str_replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the actual text present, instead of what it looks like on html browser and actual text is &nbsp ; and not a space. Try this php code,

```
$str = "<p>Some text here</p>\n<p>More text here</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>Some text</p>";
echo "Before:\n";
echo $str;
$str = str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $str);
echo "\n\nAfter:\n";
echo $str;
```

Comment: Your solution does work but it doesn't apply to what I have in my $data (which is: `<h3>Votre trajet</h3>
   <div class="septraf"> </div>
   <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Dans les 2 sens</span> :<br>- arrêt Mimosas reporté à l'arrêt provisoire placé route de Vannes au niveau de la station essence<br>- arrêt Cravate reporté à l'arrêt Ferrière</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>` )

Comment: @Loïc If this answer "works" but it doesn't work for your project, then your question is Unclear.  You should update your question to be sufficiently accurate so volunteers don't waste their time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't really determine what character is inside your `<p>...</p>` you can use a regex to remove all the `<p>` elements that contains 2 or less characters.
For example, you could use `preg_replace('/<p>.{0,2}<\/p>/', '' , $data);`.

Comment: Thank's so much !! That worked perfectly as I wanted to ;)